# How to color the text of RichTextBox depending on the prefix of the string?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I would like to color all the strings inside of the richtextbox. For example, if the prefix of a particular string is

1. `Received:` then it should be blue
2. `Send:` then it should be red
3. `Info:` then it should be green

`*The way I output the text in the RichTextBox is by ascending order, it means that all the newest messages will be outputted at the top of the RichTextBox, the old ones will go down.`

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Codes:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim msg_info As String = Nothing

        If RB_Info.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Info: "
        End If
        If RB_Send.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Send: "
        End If
        If RB_Received.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Received: "
        End If

        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, msg_info & TextBox1.Text & ControlChars.NewLine)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Edit:** I've tried applying this sub, but it changes the color of all items in ListBox

```
Sub HighlightPhrase(box As RichTextBox, phrase As String, color As Color)
        Dim pos As Integer = box.SelectionStart
        Dim s As String = box.Text
        Dim ix As Integer = 0
        While True
            Dim jx As Integer = s.IndexOf(phrase, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            If jx < 0 Then
                Exit While
            End If
            box.SelectionStart = jx
            box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length
            box.SelectionColor = color
            ix = jx + 1
        End While
        box.SelectionStart = pos
        box.SelectionLength = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim msg_info As String = Nothing

        If RB_Info.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Info: "
            HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox1, "Info", Color.Blue)
        End If
        If RB_Send.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Send: "
            HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox1, "Send", Color.Green)
        End If
        If RB_Received.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Received: "
            HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox1, "Received", Color.Red)
        End If
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, msg_info & TextBox1.Text & ControlChars.NewLine)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited my solution so the new line appears at the top of the RichTextBox.

I think my solution is ugly because basically it re-paints the color of each line after a new line has been added. Imagine if the RichTextBox has thousands of lines. I think you can minimize this by keeping a limit on how many lines is in the RTB, eg 100 lines.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim msg_info As String = Nothing

        If RB_Info.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Info: "
        End If
        If RB_Send.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Send: "
        End If
        If RB_Received.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Received: "
        End If

        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, msg_info & TextBox1.Text & ControlChars.NewLine)
        ChangeColor()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeColor()

        Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(vbLf)
        Dim startPos As Integer, endPos As Integer = -1
        Dim myColor As Color

        For i = 0 To lines.Length - 2 ' minus 2 because the last one is empty string
            startPos = endPos + 1
            endPos = startPos + lines(i).Length
            RichTextBox1.Select(startPos, endPos)

            If lines(i).StartsWith("Info: ") Then myColor = Color.Red
            If lines(i).StartsWith("Send: ") Then myColor = Color.Blue
            If lines(i).StartsWith("Received: ") Then myColor = Color.Green

            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = myColor
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Alternative solution using a ListView**

You might want to look at the ListView control. If you don't want to write anything in the list, I suggest you to replace the RichTextBox with a ListView. After you add a ListView, change the `View` property to `List`.

[image]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim msg_info As String = Nothing
        Dim myColor As Color

        If RB_Info.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Info: "
            myColor = Color.Green
        End If
        If RB_Send.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Send: "
            myColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If RB_Received.Checked = True Then
            msg_info = "Received: "
            myColor = Color.Blue
        End If

        Dim li = New ListViewItem()
        li.ForeColor = myColor
        li.Text = msg_info & TextBox1.Text
        ListView1.Items.Insert(0, li)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Yes, this is great. The only thing that it missed is that the RichTextBox should output new text at the upper part of the RichTextBox. Something like this  `RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, msg_info & TextBox1.Text & ControlChars.NewLine)`